# Packaging and installing own Python program for/on Yocto

Tags: python, pip, package, yocto

I am building an embedded Linux system based on Yocto Kirkstone. The system is supposed to run some Python background programs written by me that each consist of several .py files each and use a module also written by me.

I have been trying to put together bits and pieces about how to implement the installation in an elegant way, but there are still some things missing.

What I would like to have:

- The Python code in its own repository i.e. separate from the Yocto stuff
- A recipe in a custom layer
- The recipe not listing individual files that are installed, but instead letting the program repository dictate what is installed

Other points and thoughts:

- The program repository could contains files needed to build a .whl package (or a few of them) or something similar and the recipe would then build and install those
- Each program and the library could be in their on repositories or they could also be all in one, as long as that is separate from where the Yocto stuff is kept

I can find examples of creating a recipe for simple scripts made so that the script comes along with the recipe. I can also find examples of creating .whl packages of Python programs and installing them using Pip. What I can't find is a simple but complete example of having a recipe take code from a dedicated repository and installing it.

I guess the easiest way of answering this would be naming some Python program found on the internet that I could use as an example. Does anyone have anything in mind?

I am especially interested in a sort of standard solution i.e. something that would use the tools needed the way they are intended to be used.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the **setuptools3.bbclass**.

This class is used by recipes to build a `.whl` package and then install such wheel into the target system.

Concrete and simple examples may be found across the OpenEmbedded ecosystem, for example in the [meta-python](https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/layer/meta-python/) layer within meta-openembedded:

The [gyp](http://cgit.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded/tree/meta-python/recipes-devtools/gyp/gyp_git.bb?h=master) recipe builds directly from a git repository for gyp, which contains the source files needed to build a wheel (aka the files aren't listed directly in the recipe, it simply points to the repo).

```
SRC_URI = "git://chromium.googlesource.com/external/gyp;protocol=https;branch=master \
           file://0001-Fix-for-Python-3.10-compatibility.patch \
           "
SRCREV = "caa60026e223fc501e8b337fd5086ece4028b1c6"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"
PV = "0.1+git${SRCPV}"

inherit setuptools3
```

Again the recipe is quite simple and the magic happens by using the `inherit` directive for the [setuptools3 class](https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/tree/meta/classes/setuptools3.bbclass?h=kirkstone) to override do_compile (and others) to build the wheel and then setuptools3 itself inherits the [python_pep517 class](https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/tree/meta/classes/python_pep517.bbclass?h=kirkstone) to perform installation in case you re interested in diving into the details on how it works.